# How to group several wxFrame-windows making them to be activated together

Tags: cocoa, wxwidgets

I need to make activation (i.e. putting on top) of a one `wxFrame` window trigger activation of a second (and visa versa) for both Windows and Mac.

I think the main problem here is the Mac, since it seems there's no way to activate specific window programmatically (am I wrong here?).

When I try to put both windows into a parent container on Mac (changing `wxFrame`s into `wxWindow`s), the their borders and title bars disappear.

Is there an easy way to solve the problem?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but isn't there only 1 active window at a time, i.e. on Windows?

Comment: @ababo, please describe what you want to achieve in plain English.  It is not clear from this explanation.

Comment: Imagine two windows of the same app. One is partially overlapped by other windows, the second is fully overlapped. When you click on the first app window it becomes active (i.e. to stay on top). I need the second window to become on top too when the first is activated.

Comment: In other words I want my windows to activate all together as a group, rather than individually,

Comment: @ababo, this is not possible in any OS. Only one window at any given time can be active. However, it all depends on what do you mean by active...

Comment: @ababo, I think what you need to do is to call `Raise` . https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#a54808c933f22a891c5db646f6209fa4d .

Comment: If you make the other window child of the main one, raising the parent window will also raise its child, at least under MSW.

Comment: Tried, doesn't work on Mac.